# After chrome's auto update, selenium chromedrivers become redundant : Standard way to handle this in CI Environment

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

**UseCase:**

After the chrome browser gets updated, UI automated testing with selenium ( which uses a older chromedriver) is unable to run some of the automated test-suites.

What is the standard automated way to cope-up with these updates ?

stop auto-update of chrome browser in those CI ( continuous Integration ) machines 
or 
Is there any other standard automated way of doing this ?

Comment: Chrome only gets updated once every couple months or so... why is this an issue? Just update the drivers. You should update your question with the CI system you use and any other relevant info.

Comment: BTW, they aren't "redundant", they are out of date.

Comment: @JeffC  - Thanks ! Is there any automated way of doing this ? Issue here is - a manual effort is need to go and update the drivers.Consider a case where there are 'n' number of CI machines and they are connected to internet. Chrome by default updates its version , but the drivers are not updated which left a few testcases as not runnable. The main objective is to reduce manual effort involved in this..